# How do I call a method using a variable?

Tags: java, methods, this

```
SubArray = Key.Ikey;
```

`Ikey` being the variable which holds the name of the method.

I tried:

```
SubArray = Key.(this.IKey);
```

but the compiler gave the error `identifier excpected`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are interested in **reflection**. It goes something like:

```
method = object.getClass().getMethod(methodName, param1.class, param2.class, ..);
```

So you are calling the method specified by the variable 'methodName' of the object 'object'

You can read more here [Reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160970/how-do-i-invoke-a-java-method-when-given-the-method-name-as-a-string)

and in this tutorial [link](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/methods.html)

Comment: So param1 wouldvbe whats in ()